# "Search" cookie using PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'm using a 5 stars AJAX voting sistem. When an article is rated, a cookie is added:

Name `has_voted_40` and value `40`, where 40 is the unique id of the article.

I want to check if the user has rated at least one article. How could I "search" through cookies to verify if at least one article has been rated?

For example, if a cookie of this form is found, the variable `$voted` to be set to `1`.

The only idea I have:

```
<?
    $voted=0;
    for($i=1;$i<500;$i++) {
        if(isset($_COOKIE["has_voted_".$i]))
            $voted=1;
    }
?>
```

I set the limit to 500, but the id can be bigger than 500 and I think it's not the best idea.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: I don't have any good idea, I know to do it only 'browsing' cookies using a for loop. But what should be the limit?! That's why I asked...

Comment: Generally task like this should not only rely on cookie, you'd better to save these information in database, then you can search much easier and faster.

Comment: They are also saved in database. I want to show a popup when the user votes for the fist time.

Comment: Rather than a `for` loop speculatively looking for cookies, you could use a `foreach` to look at the name of each cookie that *does* exist. But I like Nanne's answer below better, particularly since you should limit the amount of data sent in cookies as much as possible, so a simple "yes/no" is often more appropriate than lots of details you can't rely on anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you only want to know if *a* rating has been done? Why not make a variable "hasVoted" that would not be set normally, and on all votes just either make it 1, or if it exists then add one.

Now if no "hasVoted" exists, the user has not voted and otherwise it has. And you even get the number of votes for (almost) free like this :D